# Не получается настроить reverse proxy в Caddy Server получаю ошибку error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error?

Tags: windows-server

Не получается настроить reverse proxy в Caddy Server получаю ошибку error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error?

Есть Windows сервер
Windows Server IP
`10.0.0.5`

`IP 100.100.50.50`  Это ip внешный который соеденен через VPN Tunnel c нашим IP   `10.0.0.5`

В сервере указал host file
`100.100.50.50 someservice.com`

На сервере установил Insomnia и сделал через него пост

`post https://someservice.com:9444/oauth2/token`

Ответ получил успешно

На сервер установил Caddy
Caddyfile прописал
`someservice.com:9444 {reverse_proxy 100.100.50.50:9444}`

Файрволе на входящие дал разрешение на порт 80, 443, 9444 и для программу Caddy

Запустил Caddy

Теперь хочу сделать запрос через другой компьютер
локальном компьтере хост файле прописал ip сервера

`10.0.0.5 someservice.com`

Делаю запрос
`post https://someservice.com:9444/oauth2/token`

Получаю ошибку

`* Preparing request to https://someservice.com:9444/oauth2/token`

- Current time is 2023-07-07T09:25:08.910Z
- Enable automatic URL encoding
- Using default HTTP version
- Enable SSL validation
- Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
- Trying 10.0.0.5:9444...
- Connected to someservice.com(10.0.0.5) port 9444 (#163)
- ALPN, offering h2
- ALPN, offering http/1.1
- TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
- TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Unknown (21):
- TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, internal error (592):
- error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error
- Closing connection 163